# How to test HAProxy routing rules withour running HAProxy and\or backend servers

Tags: haproxy, haproxy-ingress

Is there any way to test routing rules\config without actually running HAProxy and backend servers?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest setting up a staging/test environment to do this. You can verify that the configuration is valid(***syntactically***) using the following command:

```
haproxy -c -f </path/to/haproxy.cfg>
```

However, it will not tell you if the configuration is functional from a logical perspective.

> The flag ‘-c‘, enables “check mode” and is the flag that tells HAProxy
> to test, without actually starting or restarting HAProxy.

Comment: did some edits to the original answer, if you do not agree feel free to reject the edit suggestion if you got any.